# Bug with JSON JQuery Ajax POST

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, express, post

I've tried all variations of the AJAX Post request that I can think of, and I'm still not receiving the correct request in my Express app.

```
var json = {}
var skus = [1,2,3]
json.data = {
    "test":"test",
    "aoeu":"aoeu"
} 
$.post('/jet/api/putProduct',json)
```

I've simplifed down to this code, and it's still not coming through properly.

It's appearing on the Express server in req.body as follows.

```
{data[test]: "test", data[aoeu]: "aoeu"}
```

I've tried `json["data"] = ...` and nothing.
I've tried using `$.ajax()` and nothing.
I've tried different ways of building the object / array, and nothing.

I'm using `app.use( bodyParser.json())`

I don't know where to dig deeper, but this functionality seems pretty basic, so I'm not sure where the hangup is.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for debugging? Is it an Express issue? I've spent too long on this already.

Comment: you are sending as json so `bodyParser.json()` won't work. Default contentType for jQuery ajax is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Thanks for more insight.  I was trying $.ajax() with contentType set to application/json like recommended below. The problem was with `app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })) ` I switched to true, and everything is appearing fine now.  Whew.

Comment: answer below by @TechBreak doesn't parse the data to json correctly

Answer (score 0):

You could do following to make it a little simpler,

```
var json = {
  "test":"test",
  "aoeu":"aoeu"
}
```

and send ajax post as follows,

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/jet/api/putProduct',
   type: "POST",
   data: json,
   contentType: "application/json"
});
```

So on the Express server in req.body you should get is as follows.

```
{
  "test":"test",
  "aoeu":"aoeu"
}
```

Comment: can't just set contentType without also stringifying the data